# Simultaneous triangularization of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, triangularization

Let $\mathcal{F}=\{A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_r\}$ be a triangulable commuting family of $n\times n$ matrices (that is, each $A_i$ is triangulable and $A_iA_j=A_jA_i$ for every $i,j$). I know that $\mathcal{F}$ can be simultaneous triangularization, but what is the algorithm of finding the invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}A_iP$ is triangular? As a working example consider the matrices 
$$
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
-3 & 2 & -4 \\
-1 & 0 & -1\\
 2 & -2 & 3
\end{pmatrix}\qquad
B=
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & -2 & 2 \\
-1 & 2 & -1\\
-2 & 2 & -1
\end{pmatrix}\qquad
C=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Here $AB=BA$, $AC=CA$ and $BC=CB$. In addition, the characteristic polynomials of these matrices are
$$
f_A(x)=x(x-1)(x+1)\\
f_B(x)=(x-2)(x-1)^2\\
f_C(x)=x^2(x-1)
$$
so each one of them is triangulable. Thanks!

Comment: The characteristic polynomial for $A$ seems wrong.

Comment: A typo..I fixed that ($-4$ in the 13 position). Thanks @Emilio Novati.

Comment: Do you know how to find the matrix $P$ for a single triangularizable matrix $A$?

Comment: yes, i know how to do  the trianglazation process with a single matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, it is easy. Since $A$ has $3$ distinct eigenvalues and $B,C$ commute with $A$, we can deduce that $B,C$ are polynomials in $A$ and it suffices to triangularize $A$.

In the general case.

Step 1. Find a common eigenvector of $A,B,C$.

Step 2. Proceed by recurrence.

Moreover, you can choose $P$ as an orthogonal matrix.

Comment: Thanks @loup blanc. Two questions: (1) Does the matrices $A_i$ must have a common eigenvectors? (2) What do you mean by "Proceed by recurrence"?

Comment: Yes, they do have a common eigenvector $u$. Consider a basis in the form $u,\cdots$ and use the same reasoning about the "right-lower" blocks of the new matrices.

Comment: Thanks @loup blanc for you answer.

Answer (score -1):

More explicitly: find a common eigenvector *v<sub>1</sub>* among your given matrices. Now complete a basis arbitrarily *u<sub>2</sub>,...,*u<sub>n</sub>*. Let *Q = [v,u<sub>1</sub>,...,u<sub>n</sub> ]* a matrix. Now Q<sup>-1</sup>AQ, Q<sup>-1</sup>BQ, and Q<sup>-1</sup>CQ should all have an *(n-1)* x *(n-1)* submatrix in the bottom right with only zeros in the entries of first column directly to the left of it. You then want to find a common eigenvector *w* among all of these submatrices. Let *U =[u<sub>1</sub>,...,u<sub>n</sub>]*. Then *v<sub>2</sub> =Uw*. With this update *Q = [v<sub>1</sub>,v<sub>2</sub>,u<sub>3</sub>,...,u<sub>n</sub> ] *  where u<sub>3</sub>,...,u<sub>n</sub> may have been rechosen in order to complete the space. You rinse and repeat with *n-2*, *n-3* and so on.

If you need more information check out the algorithm in the paper by Dubi: 
[image]